# Drop levels to treat 2 of them as a Control Case. Problems with regression/modelling/statistics since its not dummy?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, levels

I've stumbled upon a doubt about using droplevels in my dataset. I have 4 factors in my "Disease column".

```
BD$Etiología <- factor(BD$Etiología, levels=c(0,1,2,3,4) ,
labels= c("Control","Idiop","LMNA","BAG3","Isquémica"), ordered=FALSE)
```

Then i make a subset in order to just compare the Control Cases vs 1 of the diseases.

```
BD_C_ID <- subset(BD, Etiología=="Control" | Etiología=="Idiop")

BD_C_ID$Etiología= droplevels(BD_C_ID$Etiología) 

BD_C_ID$Etiología

[1] Control Control Control Control Control Control Control Idiop   Idiop   Control Control Control
[13] Control Idiop   Idiop   Idiop   Idiop   Idiop   Idiop   Idiop   Idiop   Idiop   Idiop   Idiop  
[25] Idiop   Idiop   Control Control Control Control Idiop   Control Control Control Control Control
[37] Idiop   Idiop   Idiop   Idiop  
Levels: Control Idiop
```

Since the first factor was unordered, and i just drop the levels i don't use. Could i treat them as a 0-1 coded value in order to use them in a `lm`, or a logistic regression? Or will there be a problem?

Also, does that apply if i use the Control VS BAG3 (0-3 in the initial code?)? Or will i need to re-level them so its 0-1 re-applying factors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is it doesn't matter. If you use them in a linear model `lm` or logistic regression, the model will use the first level as a reference level, so in this case, it is always `"Control"` . The `droplevels()` is good if you need to perform some functions with the factors, but if it is purely for `lm()` or `glm()`, these functions takes care of the factors underneath.

To illustrate this using your example:

```
set.seed(111)
BD = data.frame(
          Etiologia = sample(0:4,100,replace=TRUE),
          x = rnorm(100),
          y = rnorm(100)
                )
```

We can just do:

```
BD$E <- factor(BD$Etiologia,levels=0:4,
labels= c("Control","Idiop","LMNA","BAG3","Isquemica"))

lm(y ~ x + E,data=subset(BD,E %in% c("Control","Idiop")))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + E, data = subset(BD, E %in% c("Control", "Idiop")))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x       EIdiop  
   -0.05524      0.21596      0.30433
```

And using another comparison:

```
lm(y ~ x + E,data=subset(BD,E %in% c("Control","BAG3")))

     Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + E, data = subset(BD, E %in% c("Control", 
    "BAG3")))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x        EBAG3  
   -0.03355      0.08978     -0.21708
```

You get the same result if you do:

```
BD$Etiologia <- factor(BD$Etiologia, levels=c(0,1,2,3,4) ,
labels= c("Control","Idiop","LMNA","BAG3","Isquemica"), ordered=FALSE)

BD_C_ID <- droplevels(subset(BD, Etiologia=="Control" | Etiologia=="Idiop"))

lm(y ~ x + Etiologia,data=BD_C_ID)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + Etiologia, data = BD_C_ID)

Coefficients:
   (Intercept)               x  EtiologiaIdiop  
      -0.05524         0.21596         0.30433
```